# Can the SQL query string length in Oracle SQL cause Exception?

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, plsql

I have a SQL query of length **3261** characters for an application that errors out with the following exception in the logs

```
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908 
║   ) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by: 
║   com.myapp.DiagException: Execution of the 
║   SQL query failed. SQL query was: 'null' at 
║   com.myapp.plsql.PLSQLReportProcessor 
║   .displaySQLResults(PLSQLReportProcessor.java:622) 

║   com.myapp.engine.DiagRunnable.run(DiagRunnable.java:68) 
║    at     java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:442) 
║   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) at 
║   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:139) ... 2 more Caused 
║   by: java.sql.SQLException: Null SQL statement passed to prepareStatement at 
║   weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Connection.prepareStatement(Connection.java:548) at 
║   com.myapp.engine.impl.report.plsql.PLSQLReportProcessor 
║   .displaySQLResults(PLSQLReportProcessor.java:583) ... 17 more 
║   Fix Information: An unexpected error was encountered. Please contact your 
║   system administrator.
```

Are there any limits to the length of the sql query that might be causing this error or could it be the result of bad data like one of the columns being null?

I am also able to run this long sql query from SQL developer. It's only erroring out when executing through the application when being passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Ask Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3A%3A%3A%3AP11_QUESTION_ID:41742083561301):

> In plsql for example, execute immediate is limited to 32k because PLSQL itself is limited 
>   to 32k in a varchar variable.  However, you can use dbms_sql to parse an ARRAY that can 
>   be huge -- megabytes in size.

Comment: The character count in this sql query is 3261 characters. It doesn't seem to be over the 32k limit. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Pha3drus Based on the docs, you're right. Sadly I can't tell what's causing the error you get, but it's likely not the length of the query.